# How to get code input as component in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a webpage that has a code editor where the user can write code in react.js and run the test script on the terminal with the code that the user input. I have a test script using `@testing-library/react`. I'd like to get a code input from the text editor which is currently just a string and render it as a component on the test file so that I can run the test with the user's code input.

The test file is looking like this.

```
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import ToggleMessage from "./ToggleMessage";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";

test("Render ToggleMessage component and check if it has text:'Want to buy a new car?'", () => {

  const { getByText } = render(<ToggleMessage />); //<= Here I want to render codeInput as component.

  const linkElement = getByText(/Want to buy a new car?/i);
  expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

This is ToggleMessage.js where getting codeInput as a prop from a text editor.

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";

function ToggleMessage({ codeInput }) {

  const [display, setDisplay] = useState("none");
  const toggle = () => {
    display === "none" ? setDisplay("block") : setDisplay("none");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <a href="#" onClick={toggle}>
        Want to buy a new car?
      </a>
      <p style={{ display }}>Call +11 22 33 44 now!</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ToggleMessage;
```

Are there any ways to pass the codeInput prop to the test file and render it as a component? Any suggestions or help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: if `codeInput` is a prop you can mock it

Comment: Check out this answer on a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65417030/14874263